# Ruby on Rails push notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, websocket, push-notification

Is there any gem, anything I can use to push notifications from server to the web application in a Rails App?

This means not having to call an ajax request from time to time.

:: UPDATE ::
Forgot to mention one important requirement which is that I'm using Rails 3.2

Comment: Something like [Rails 4 streaming](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html)?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, but I'm using Rails 3.2. I'll update my question

Comment: More or less. Websockets and streaming are still somehow confusing for me. Streaming seems to be changed quite a lot in version 4 of rails, for better. I have to spend some time on it. As this is not a priority task for me now I'm re-evaluating this in a couple of weeks, for the time being I would like to gather some choices to consider by then.

Comment: But now you know to which direction you are able to see?)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with Faye gem  in rails. There is a great railscast on this.
[Faye](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye)

Answer (score 1):

You can use websockets for ruby to establish the client-server communication. For example use the [*websocket* gem](https://github.com/imanel/websocket-ruby) for it.

Also, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767268/best-ruby-on-rails-websocket-tool) topic.